# In Heritrix crawler tool how to extract the contents from crawled urls

Tags: java, spring, heritrix

Am new to heritrix tool and now i am able to crawl the web pages from www and now want to extract the contents of the crawled urls.

please help me any one.please.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: heritrix is a crawler, after you crawl the data use Jsoup / scrapy to parse HTML and extract the data

Comment: hi could you please tell me in detail with example .thanks .

Comment: Hi any one help me. my file name is WEB-20130828123516395-00000-7675~tharma~8443.warc.gz .i want to extract this file. can any one help me.please. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: look at 13.2. Reading arc files http://crawler.archive.org/articles/developer_manual/arcs.html#arcreader,

Comment: Thanks for the comments Mehul Rathod.But i had extracted the file that day itself with found another way of phython script.

Comment: Awesome, sounds great. May be you can post your answer here so if anyone else is looking to do the same they can use the script too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 1.first download the file  wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tgz or higher version as root user.
 2. change the directory to installed python
 3. example /opt/python3.3/;
 4. configure the files ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
 5.make
 6. sudo make install
 7. /opt/python3.3/bin/python3
 8.opt/python3.3/bin/pyvenv ~/py33
 9.source ~/py33/bin/activate
 10. wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
 11.python distribute_setup.py  
 12. easy_install pip
 13. pip install bottle
 14. pip install warcat 
 15. if successfully installed warcat then check whether your warcat is installed or not.
 16. python3 -m warcat --help after enter then we can see some help commands like, list,concat,extract etc..
 17.python3 -m warcat list example/at.warc.gz
 this is worked for me ..enjoy
```